# Did I find a java.util.Calendar bug?

Tags: java, unit-testing, calendar, clone

I have the following test:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import org.junit.Test;
public class CalendarBug {
    private static final TimeZone UTC_ZONE = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");// +0 hours
    private static final TimeZone IST_ZONE = TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST");// +5 hours 30 minutes

    @Test
    public void calendarBug() {
        Calendar utcCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(UTC_ZONE);
        utcCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
        utcCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
        utcCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 12);
        utcCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
        utcCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        utcCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        SimpleDateFormat utcFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" );
        utcFormatter.setTimeZone(UTC_ZONE);
        System.out.println( "If I have this line commented out, the test fails: " + utcFormatter.format(utcCalendar.getTime()));
        Calendar istCalendar = (Calendar) utcCalendar.clone();
        assertEquals(UTC_ZONE, istCalendar.getTimeZone());
        istCalendar.setTimeZone(IST_ZONE);
        assertEquals(istCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), utcCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
    }
}
```

If you run the test, it works. However if you comment out the `System.out.println` line with the formatter inside, it fails:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<1428813000979> but was:<1428832800979>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:647)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:128)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:472)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:456)
    at xxx.yyy.CalendarBug.calendarBug(CalendarBug.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

It seems that the formatter changes the internal state of the `utcCalendar` and it causes the test to pass.

Did I misuse anything here? Is there an open bug in JDK for this?

Java version:

```
liptak@XXXXXX:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I am not able to replicate the same in Java 1.7.0_21

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : I posted an incorrect answer in haste, due to reading only part of your code.

Here's a completely new answer:

First of all, the Javadoc of Calendar states when the time of the Calendar is actually calculated :

> **Getting and Setting Calendar Field Values**
>
> The calendar field values can be set by calling the *set* methods. **Any field values set in
> a Calendar will not be interpreted until it needs to calculate its
> time value (milliseconds from  the Epoch)** or values of the calendar
> fields. **Calling** the  get, **getTimeInMillis**, **getTime**, add and roll
> **involves such calculation**.

The behavior you encountered is not a bug.

You create a `Calendar` instance and then create a clone of that instance. Then you change the timezone of the cloned instance.

However, there are two scenarios :

1. The time of the original Calendar object is calculated prior to creating the clone, as a result of calling `utcCalendar.getTime()` in your print statement. The cloned Calendar contains this time, so changing the timezone doesn't change that time (since `getTimeInMillis()` returns `UTC milliseconds from the epoch`, so it doesn't depend on which timezone is used). The time is not recalculated when you call `assertEquals(istCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), utcCalendar.getTimeInMillis())`, so the test passes.
2. The time of the original Calendar object is not calculated prior to creating the clone. Then you change the time zone of the cloned instance. Now, when you call `assertEquals(istCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), utcCalendar.getTimeInMillis())`, the times in both Calendar instances are calculated, and they are different, since 10AM IST and 10AM UTC are not the same time (they are 5.5 hours apart, which is exactly the difference between `1428813000979` and `1428832800979`).

Comment: So why is it not a bug?

Comment: Still I would expect that the field values are cloned and the getTime call in the assertEquals will calculate the same value for both calendars.

Comment: Then the real question is: what is the internal state of a calendar? The field values or the UTC time in millis? What should be really cloned?

Comment: You would expect that calling any method whose name starts with "get" would not alter the observable state of the object.

Comment: @GáborLipták I completely changed my answer

Comment: So it is a bug in setTimeZone method :) I would expect that the universal time behind the Calendar remains the same no matter if I called getTime before or not.

Comment: @GáborLipták You could argue that calling `setTimeZone` should clear the `isTimeSet` flag and require a recalculation of the time, but you can also argue the opposite. If you want to convert 3/12/2015 10:00:00 AM UTC to a different timezone (i.e. find out what time is it in IST timezone when it's 10AM UTC), you shouldn't recalculate the time when changing the timezone. If you recalculate the timezone after calling setTime, you are calculating a different time (10AM IST).

Comment: It is still silly that setTimeZone changes the UTC time behind the Calendar if the calculation did not happen before, but does not change if it happened. I would not say that it is obvious from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this more of an expected behavior since you are cloning.

First off, the time values on those two calendars can not be same as IST will have an off set of 19800000 , and that's reflecting in above `AssertionError`.
The correct assertion would be :

```
assertNotEquals(istCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), utcCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

When you call `utcCalendar.getTime();` to print formatted output you are actually changing internal state of the calendar object to have `isTimeComputed` to `true`. This is to avoid recomputing of time when `getTime()` or `getTime Millis()` is called again. The same flag carries on as `true` to the **cloned** object `istCalendar` and hence time is not re-computed on `istCalendar` when you call `getTimeInMillis`.

This actually causes both of the calendars erroneously print same milliseconds.

This is not a bug, I would say. This is rather a **side effect of clone.**